# Iterating through a vector which contains a custom class C++

Tags: c++, function, vector, overloading, member

I hope someone can help me. In an effort to be more specific about what I really need, and trim down my code, I have changed from having a vector purely of my Class, to having a vector of objects of a new class, of which my original class is a type within.

I hope I have explained myself clearly up until this point. I will show the relevant classes:

```
class screen_area

{

private:

int my_id, my_x, my_y, my_width, my_height;
bool active=true;

public:

screen_area (int button_id=0, int x=0, int y=0, int width=0, int height=0, bool isactive=true)
{

    my_id = button_id;
    my_x = x;
    my_y = y;

    my_width = width;
    my_height = height;
    active = isactive;

}


~screen_area()
{}



class bet 
{

private:

    int wager = 0;
    int multiplier = 0; 

public:

    screen_area area;

    bet(int wager, int multiplier, screen_area area)
    {};

    ~bet()
    {};
```

There is a little more to them, but this is the bread and butter. Now previously I had used a member function within "screenarea", to return any value I had wanted from a specific object:

```
int getvalue(int value)
    {
    switch(value)
        {
            case 1 :
                return my_id;
            case 2 :
                return my_x;
            case 3 :
                return my_y;
            case 4 :
                return my_width;
            case 5 :
                return my_height;
            case 6 :
                return active;
        }
    }
```

And I have modified a lookup function to use this member function on the screenarea that is a type contained within "bet".

```
int returnbuttonid(int mousex, int mousey, std::vector<bet> *buttons)
{

    for (auto ep : *buttons )
    {
        if ((ep.area.getvalue(2) > mousex) && (ep.area.getvalue(3) > mousey))
            {int id_value = ep.area.getvalue(1);
            return id_value;
            }
    }   
}
```

However... it returns garbage. I'm clearly missing something, but I am going through it logically and it all seems to make sense.

Sorry in advance if it is something simple! And I appreciate that this may seem long winded but I would really appreciate some help!

And just to be super clear... this is how I am calling it:

```
vector<bet> localbuttons;       //Declaration of Vector
    load_map("data.dat", &localbuttons);    //load buttonmap using function

    int buttonpressed = returnbuttonid(100,300, &localbuttons);
```

In response to a very speedy comment. It's clear that the problem at least starts with an unpublished piece of code. My vector of "bet" is not being filled with the arguments I am passing to it when I try to overload the constructor. I presumed I had corrected the syntax correctly when I created the new class "bet", but after probing the vector it is not showing any data.

In my function load_map:

```
bool load_map(std::string path, std::vector<bet> *buttons)
{

    //setup file
    ifstream inputFile( path.c_str() );
//
//The stuff in the middle here is irrelevant
//and I've take it out to make this tidier

         buttons->push_back(bet(0,0, screen_area(id,x,y,width,height, true)));

        }

return 0;

}
```

Now the only part of this that has changed since I had this function was working is:

```
buttons->push_back(bet(0,0, screen_area(id,x,y,width,height, true)));
```

So I am guessing this is where the problem originates. The variables are not overloading the default screen_area constructor. So when I:

```
cout << localbuttons[1].area.my_id << endl;
```

I always see whatever value I place in the default constructor. It is "0" in the constructor I have posted here, but if I change it, it changes correspondingly.

And I shouldn't have said garbage, I was at fault for thinking I had correctly identified the area of the problem, and trying to be concise. So I guess I should be asking first... How can I correctly overload this "screenarea" constructor?

Comment: "It returns garbage" does not provide enough information about the problem for anyone to really help you. There are a few issues with the code you've shown but without a [mcve] it's almost impossible to know where the issue (whatever it is) could be. Are you checking if `load_map()` actually works? Does the vector contain the data you think it does? Have you stepped through in the debugger to see what point the "garbage" is coming from?

Comment: ok thanks for this feedback. I will update the question to respond to what you've pointed out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was in the Constructor of the Bet class.

After having a look here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

I rewrote the constructor in the Bet class:

```
bet(int w, int m, int button_id=0, int x=0, int y=0, 
    int width=0, int height=0, bool isactive=true) 

        : area(button_id, x, y, width, height, isactive),

        wager(w), multiplier(m)
{};
```

My apologies if I wasted anyone time with misdirection, and thanks for the sensible advice from Jonathon Potter.

I'm not sure why I thought you could call constructors within parentheses. My compiler didn't seem to complain about it, but from what I can gather - I was just creating a temporary object.